# How to test hosting before picking one?

Tags: ping, web-hosting

I'm looking for fast and cheap hosting at the moment and I don't want to rely on users opinions only (many if not most of them are sponsored by, or are actually from, the companies themselves anyway).

Let's say I have 100 addresses from each:

- Media Temple,
- Dreamhost,
- Bluehost,
- Hostgator
- GoDaddy,
- etc.

I know I could ping them all and compare response times and such, but are there other, more robust ways of testing how quickly these sites respond?

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of tools out there to test this. Simply Google the string "Web page testing". For example, webpagetest.org allows you to select a location and gives a nice breakdown on a lot of statistics.

The best bet though is to use the free trial and upload *your* site to the host and see how it performs under testing.